# PHP AJAX Show table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fuelphp

I have a form to create events in which we have 2 fiedls from date and to date:
Now i used ajax so when selecting both dates it should show table data on the same page below.

My AJax code:

```
function showAjaxData(fromdate,todate)
{
    var from_date=jQuery("#fromdatepicker").val();
    var to_date=jQuery("#todatepicker").val();

    var from_date= from_date.replace(/-|\//g, '-');
    var to_date= to_date.replace(/-|\//g, '-');

    var data =
    {       
        from_date    : from_date,
        to_date      : to_date
    }
    jQuery.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "Events/Calender_Ajax.htm",
        data: data,
        success: function(response)
        { 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

Any Help!

Comment: your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Some questions:

1. Are you sure you want to send your data to Calender_Ajax.htm file? Not php?

2. If you receive any answer, you should do something with it. It will come in response variable in your success function. At least try to console.log() it.

Comment: And most important, how do you call your ajax function? click / change or something else?